# How to rewrite class into the function constructor

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to rewrite a class into the function constructor.

I have an initial code:

```
class Car{
    constructor(brand){
        this.brand = brand
    }
    get brand(){
        if (this._brand) console.log(this._brand)
        else console.log("Don't forget to pick a car!")
    }
    set brand(value){
        if (value == "Tesla") this._brand = value
        else console.log("Choose another car")
    }
}

let car = new Car("BWM")
```

And i ended up with this:

```
function Car(brand){
    this.brand = brand
    Object.defineProperty(this, "brand",{
        get(){
            if (this._brand) console.log(this._brand)
            else console.log("Don't forget to pick a car!")
        },
        set(value){
            if (value == "Tesla") this._brand = value
            else console.log("Choose another car")
        }
    })
}

let car = new Car("BMW")
```

It works not quite the same though. Running the initial code i got the console.log("Choose another car") right away, but in mine, there's no such output in the beginning. So, is it possible to make it work exactly the same as the initial code?

I'm also wondering: 

1. Is it possible to add getter or setter straight to F.prototype? 

2. As i understand `get brand()` and `set brand()` in the initial code are located in Car.prototype. But the new object car has property `this.brand = brand` on its own lexical environment, thus it shouldn't go and look for setters and getters somewhere else on protytype chain, nevertheless it does. Why?

Comment: You need to put `this.brand = brand` *after* the `defineProperty`

Comment: @Seblor thanks it works now, but still a little unclear.  Why does it work with a class then? Following the same logic get and set haven't been initialized by the time constructor finished its part.

Comment: It works with a class because the properties are set before the constructor is called. That allows you to call methods (or use computed properties) within the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Is it possible to add getter or setter straight to F.prototype

You have to add your methods to the prototype of the function itself.

You can keep using `Object.defineProperty` to do this if you have a specific reason to do so, but you can also just directly add the property to the prototype this way:

`Car.prototype = { /* methods & properties */ }`

Example:

```js
class Car {
  constructor(brand) {
    this.brand = brand
  }
  get brand() {
    if (this._brand) console.log(this._brand)
    else console.log("Don't forget to pick a car!")
  }
  set brand(value) {
    if (value == "Tesla") this._brand = value
    else console.log("Choose another car")
  }
}

let car = new Car("BWM")

function CarF(brand) {
  this.brand = brand
}

CarF.prototype = {
  get brand() {
    if (this._brand) console.log(this._brand)
    else console.log("Don't forget to pick a car!")
  },
  set brand(value) {
    if (value == "Tesla") this._brand = value
    else console.log("Choose another car")
  }
}

let car2 = new CarF("BMW")
```

Just in case you were curious, here's how you do it with `Object.defineProperty`. But it's a little more verbose having to do this for every property you want to add to the class.

```js
function Car(brand) {
  this.brand = brand
}

Object.defineProperty(Car.prototype, 'brand', {
  get() {
    if (this._brand) console.log(this._brand)
    else console.log("Don't forget to pick a car!")
  },
  set(value) {
    if (value == "Tesla") this._brand = value
    else console.log("Choose another car")
  }
})

const car = new Car("BMW")
```

Comment: But in this case i would lose the constructor property. Is there a way to do exactly the same saving the constructor, something like: CarF.prototype[get brand] = function(){}.

Comment: What do you mean lose the constructor property? The constructor for a class created using a function is the function body itself. These two examples behave exactly the same.

Comment: what i meant is that if we use console.dir(CarF) before CarF.prototype = {} is executed, there will be the prototype property and constructor inside of the prototype. And as far as I know: CarF.prototype.constructor == CarF, accordingly car2.constructor == CarF. But as soon as CarF.prototype = {} is executed car2.construcotr != CarF, because we basically just reassigned the whole prototype object of the CarF and lost the constructor. That's why i asked for a possibility to modify it rather than reassign.

Comment: But the second option is exactly what i needed, i just put Object.defineProperty inside the function Car body before this.brand = brand and it worked. Thanks!